# PDO prepared statements PHP issue

Tags: php

Part of this prepared insert statement works, the other does not and I cannot see why because I am not getting an error.

I tried the different options, even mysqli just not winning. PDO does contain the statement $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project","root","");
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    echo "Connected successfully";

    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' &&  isset($_POST['submit']));

    if(
        !empty($_POST['skill_level_1'])
        && !empty($_POST['skill_level_2'])
        && !empty($_POST['skill_level_3'])

        && isset($_POST['skill_1'])
        && isset($_POST['skill_experience_1'])
        && isset($_POST['skill_2'])
        && isset($_POST['skill_experience_2'])
        && isset($_POST['skill_3'])
        && isset($_POST['skill_experience_3'])

    ){

        foreach($_POST['skill_level_1'] as $selected) {
            $GLOBALS['skill_level_1'] = $selected;
        }
        foreach($_POST['skill_level_2'] as $selected) {
            $GLOBALS['skill_level_2'] = $selected;
        }
        foreach($_POST['skill_level_3'] as $selected) {
            $GLOBALS['skill_level_3'] = $selected;
        }
        $skill_1 = strip_tags(trim($_POST['skill_1']));
        $skill_experience_1 = strip_tags(trim($_POST['skill_experience_1']));
        $skill_2 = strip_tags(trim($_POST['skill_2']));
        $skill_experience_2 = strip_tags(trim($_POST['skill_experience_2']));
        $skill_3 = strip_tags(trim($_POST['skill_3']));
        $skill_experience_3 = strip_tags(trim($_POST['skill_experience_3']));

        $stmt = $dbh ->prepare("INSERT INTO dbtable
(
skill_level_1, skill_level_2, skill_level_3,
skill_1, skill_experience_1, 
skill_2, skill_experience_2, 
skill_3, skill_experience_3
)VALUES(
:skill_level_1, :skill_level_2, :skill_level_3,
:skill_1, :skill_experience_1, 
:skill_2, :skill_experience_2, 
:skill_3, :skill_experience_3
)");

// $stmt->execute(array(':skill_level_1' => $skill_level_1, ':skill_level_2' => $skill_level_2, ':skill_level_3' => $skill_level_3));

        $stmt->bindParam(':skill_level_1',$skill_level_1);
        $stmt->bindParam(':skill_level_2',$skill_level_2);
        $stmt->bindParam(':skill_level_3',$skill_level_3);

        $stmt->bindParam(':skill_1',$skill_1);
        $stmt->bindParam(':skill_experience_1',$skill_experience_1);

        $stmt->bindParam(':skill_2',$skill_2);
        $stmt->bindParam(':skill_experience_2',$skill_experience_2);

        $stmt->bindParam(':skill_3',$skill_3);
        $stmt->bindParam(':skill_experience_3',$skill_experience_3);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo "Success";

    }//end if

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

So it works for the part skill_level_1, skill_level_2, skill_level_3 which are check boxes. But the input boxes do not work. I thought that taking away strip tags might make a difference but it does not. I tried a mysqli connection and statement and it does not work either.

Comment: You should normalize your database.

Comment: It sounds like your inputs aren't working, not the prepare, if the input boxes aren't working. Don't both with strip_tags, since that won't affect your query when using prepared statements.

Comment: Your `$skill_level_` variables aren't defined at all. You're assigning them to $_GLOBALS, but not to the variables you're binding.

Comment: Seems like your code is a lot more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: The `foreach` loops are overwriting the same global variable each time.

Comment: Why would you expect `strip_tags` to have any effect on this? Strings with tags in them have no special meaning to PDO or MySQL.

Comment: Try using `var_dump($_POST);` to see if all the parameters are what you expect.

Comment: @Dharman - I will try to normalise the DB! Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar - the foreach loops are part of the code that works because the output is contained in the loop and then placed into a global variable.

Comment: @Aynber - the strip tags in insert statements work in other parts of my code. I really just want to be sure I don't get injected but I agree, it probably is overkill.

Comment: `strip_tags` is absolutely useless regarding SQL injection. It's used to prevent XSS if you display the results of a query in HTML. It seems like you just throw these things together without really thinking about how they work.

Comment: There's no output in the `foreach` loops. They're just setting the global variable to the last element of the array.

Comment: Thanks Guys I found the issue. I had a capital letter in the HTML name for the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys I found the issue. 
I had a capital letter in the HTML name for the input field.

I also found it helped to order the columns in the database to match the order for the PHP being written to it. This enabled me to then go back and double check the HTML.